# Differential rig categories

Tags: ct.category-theory

Note: this is a crossposting. The same thread appeared on the Category Theory channel in zulip, but since the latter requires access I can't really forward the message to people that do not have a zulip account or access to the channel.

> **tl; dr:** weird things happen if $\partial$ is an endofunctor of a monoidal category that satisfies the Leibniz property $\partial(AB) = \partial A .B + A.\partial B$; the derivative of $1$ is a mysterious object.

Now to the question: the idea is really simple, and I will lazily summarise it in the abstract of the draft-of-a-paper I am writing. (Jokes apart, I find it quite self-explanatory of the general motivation I had, when this project began)

[image]

Now, if $\mathcal C$ is a rig category, in the sense that a monoidal structure $\otimes$ distributes over coproducts, a derivation is just an endofunctor $\partial : \mathcal C \to \mathcal C$ with the property that

- $\partial(A\cup B) \cong \partial A \cup \partial B$
- $\partial(A\otimes B) \cong \partial A \otimes B \cup A\otimes\partial B$.

As a general rule, one knows to be after some deep Mathematics when a seemingly innocuous assumption yields unexpected or counterintuitive results . This is the case here, because from these very natural assumptions most of the theory of differential rings carries over, with one, eminent, painful exception: there is absolutely no reason why the derivative of the monoidal unit is zero (=the initial object of the rig).

Let me offend your intelligence by recalling that if if $R$ is a differential ring, with derivation $d$, then $d1=d(1\cdot 1)= d1 +d1$; now, since the additive monoid of $R$ is cancellative, we get $d1=0$. In fact, in differential semiring theory, the most you can get is that the derivative of $1$ is an additive idempotent. Now, some authors require $d1=0$ as an axiom of a differential semiring, essentially because if this is not required, $d$ is not well-defined: $d(a)=d(a\cdot 1) = da + a \cdot d1$, which in its own right is $da + a\cdot d1 + a\cdot d1$, which... on the other hand, there are examples of semirings where *every* object is an additive idempotent (posets with $\vee$, an eminent instance of which are co-Heyting algebras, that carry [interesting operations](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/co-Heyting+boundary) that satisfy the axioms of a derivation.

When one moves to true categories things get way hairier, essentially because $\partial 1 = \partial 1 + \partial 1$ entails a whole lot of counterintuitive properties: I will list the ones that I found until now.

- First, $\partial 1$ must be "empty or big", in the sense that -for example in the category of sets- a set $A$ such that $A+A\cong A$ is either empty or infinite.
- On the other hand, in the category of *finite* sets, $A$ can only be empty; same in the category of finite dimensional vector spaces, where $d=\dim V = 2d$ has 0 (thus the zero space) as unique solution. Same, in every category with a decent choice of dimension $\mathcal C \to \mathbb N$. (What are examples of these categories? Do they have a name)?
- On another hand, sometimes $\partial 1 = \partial 1 + \partial 1$ is forced to have just trivial solutions due to the request that this equality is in some sense natural; for example, let $\partial$ be a derivation in a category of functors $\mathcal A \to Set$; then, $\partial 1$ is a functor $\mathcal A \to Set$ such that $F \cong F + F$, and naturally so; such functors are few, because no bijection $FA\cong FA + FA$ can be natural if the domain $\mathcal A$ is just a little bit nontrivial. I have asked a similar question on zulip for the exact purpose of establishing this obstruction result.
- In an abstract category of course you can't uniquely attach to an object information about how big it is; but you still have morphisms and the Yoneda lemma! So, let's stick $\partial 1$ in the hom-set $\hom(\partial 1,Z)$ for a generic object $Z$; the fact that $\partial 1\cong \partial 1 + \partial 1$ yields $\hom(\partial 1, Z) \cong \hom(\partial 1+\partial 1, Z)\cong \hom(\partial 1,Z) \times \hom(\partial 1, Z)$. Now *this* is interesting, because $\hom(\partial 1,Z)$ can only be empty, a singleton or infinite. Let me sum up: a property of $\mathcal C$ that -at least a priori- has nothing to do with its size, the presence of a differential structure, imposes some conditions on the numerosity of some of its hom-sets; if a category is finite, thus, $\hom(\partial 1, Z)$ is either empty or a singleton, and in particular it must be a singleton when $Z=\partial 1 $. Again, having a differential structure and being finite entails that $\partial 1$ is a "rigid" object, in the sense that the monoid of endomorphisms of $\partial 1$ is trivial. What is the precise reason why a differential structure imposes properties on the underlying graph of a rig category?
- More on this: whenever there is an extension $\partial 1 \hookrightarrow A$ in $\mathcal C$, there must be a monomorphism $\hom(\partial 1, \partial 1) \hookrightarrow \hom(\partial 1, A)$, so that if the domain, endomorphisms of $\partial 1$, is infinite, the codomain, arrows $\partial 1 \to A$, can only be bigger. The endomorphisms of $\partial 1$ clearly are "something special"! And this is why I would like to get to know them better: let $M=\hom(\partial 1,\partial 1)$ for short; then, from $M\cong M^2 = M\times M$ one easily gets, by induction, that $M\cong M^n$ for every finite $n$. How many monoids with this property do you know, apart the terminal one?
- Let's go deeper in the white rabbit's hole: if $\partial 1 \cong \partial 1 + \partial 1$, this means that $\partial 1$ is naturally a coalgebra for the "leave it or double it" functor $S : A\mapsto A +A$, in such a way that there is a unique map

  $$\begin{array}{ccc}  \partial 1 &\cong& \partial 1 + \partial 1 \\  \downarrow && \downarrow \\   C &\cong& C + C  \end{array}$$
  between $\partial 1$ and the terminal coalgebra of $S$; but wait, in the category of topological space $C$ is the Cantor set! What just happened here?
- Another interesting idea related to the perks and shortcomings of being $\partial 1$ is the following: as an endofunctor, $\partial$ might have interesting fixed points, and there is a standard procedure to build its initial algebra and terminal coalgebra. One could legitimately call such an object "Eulerian" or "Neperian", for obvious reasons (the most reasonable is that "exponential object" already means something else).

  Initial algebras are trivial, in that $\partial 0=0$ by using the Leibniz rule. On the other hand, the triviality of terminal coalgebras is governed by $\partial 1$, in the sense that (assuming the terminal object is the monoidal unit, that's what is called a semicartesian monoidal category)

  $$ 1\leftarrow \partial 1 \leftarrow \partial\partial 1 \leftarrow \partial\partial\partial 1 \leftarrow \dots $$

  and the first ordinal $\lambda$ for which the transition morphism $v : \partial^\lambda 1 \to \partial^{\lambda + 1} 1$ is invertible realises the terminal coalgebra. Now, what is this map? What is the result of applying $\partial$ many times to $1$? Well, since $\partial 1 = \partial 1 + \partial 1$, and $\partial$ is linear, $\partial\partial 1 = \partial (\partial 1 + \partial 1) = \partial \partial 1 + \partial \partial 1$, thus the entire cochain is made by coalgebras for the functor $\_ + \_$ (even more, by coalgebras whose coalgebra map is invertible: how many such algebras are there? What's their shape?).

So. All these questions are vague and somewhat alluding to the fact that I do not have a clear picture of what's going on: indeed, I have no idea which wa to turn: what am I after? "What is" the derivative of 1 in a differential ring, like, really? How shall one interpret each of the strange properties that I have outlined?

**Edit**: I think I didn't notice a very simple proof that $\hom(\partial 1,\partial 1)$ is always the trivial monoid; from $\partial 1 \cong \partial 1 + \partial 1$ one gets, by induction, $\partial 1 \cong \mathbb N \cdot \partial 1$, where $\mathbb N\cdot A$ is the set $\coprod_{n\in \mathbb N} A$. Now,
$$
\begin{align*}
M=\hom(\partial 1,\partial 1) &\cong \hom(\mathbb N \cdot \partial 1,\partial 1) \\ 
&\cong \mathbb N \pitchfork \hom(\partial 1,\partial 1) = M^{\mathbb N}
\end{align*}
$$ where $\mathbb N \pitchfork A = \prod_{n\in\mathbb N} A$ for a set $A$; now, a very elementary cardinality argument says that $M\cong M^{\mathbb N}$ can only be true if $M=\{*\}$.

Comment: Can you give a slightly more precise definition of a derivation ? Namely you say "with the property that" - for the first property, it's reasonable enough that you mean "$\partial$ preserves coproducts", but for the second one, do you mean that a natural isomorphism is part of the data, and it satisfies the "obvious" coherence conditions, or do you just require the existence of a natural isomorphism ?

Comment: I think that the natural condition is "$\partial\circ\otimes = 1\otimes\partial + \partial \otimes 1$", so the most natural you can get. But I'm not sure this does not rule out interesting examples...

Comment: What's your "elementary cardinality argument" ?  $\mathbb R\cong \mathbb R^\mathbb N$ holds as sets by an elementary cardinality argument, and in fact it is even true as $\mathbb Q$-vector spaces (by a slightly less elementary cardinality argument)

Comment: In't it true that if $a,b,c$ are three cardinals and $a < b, c>1$ then $c^a < c^b$?

Comment: These are exactly the reasons I believe set theory is a scam by the way...

Comment: No unfortunately it isn't the case, for $c=2$ I believe it's independent of ZFC, but for larger $c$ there are explicit counterexamples in ZF (without the C !) : $(2^\mathbb N)^\mathbb N = 2^{\mathbb N \times \mathbb N} = 2^\mathbb N$. You apply this knowing that $\mathbb R = 2^\mathbb N$ and do some reasoning about the sizes of bases and you get my previous claim